# Variable height header and 100% height content (eventyually with iframe), scrollable on mobile, no superfluous scrollbars

Tags: css, height

As in title, I want to insert a responsive variable height top header in my pages. Content should take the remaining height. In some cases content is an iframe (height = 100%). I'd like to not have superfluous scrollbars and touch scrolling working well on mobiles.
Also the site in the iframe should remain responsive if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this for CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/K64Mm/6/
Variable height, content 100% height (supports even iframe 100% height), no superfluous scrollbars, scrollable on touch devices, responsive iframe.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top topBar">

    </div> 
    <div class="content">
        <iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://www.zeffirino.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

.wrapper { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-bottom: 45px; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
.top { height: 45px; background-color: red; }
.content { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: auto !important; }
.content iframe { display: block; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Height is fixed to 45px. It's not variable.